# Changing the base color of a theme - Ext JS 6

Tags: javascript, extjs, themes, sencha-touch, extjs6

Is it possible to change the base code of a theme in Ext JS without creating a new custom theme?

If there is, can someone please provide a method for doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

If your application is built by Sencha Cmd, easy as cake.

From your `app` directory with the javascript source code of `Application.js`, navigate to `..\sass\src`.

Now create a file `Application.scss` which contains:

```
$base-color: dynamic(#fc0)
```

Call `sencha app build production` and you will find that your application now uses the worst yellow I could find, instead of the original blue.

(I have tested against an application with Triton theme, there are some issues with gray and classic theme because they rely on background images which are not affected by a changed base color.)

Comment: While this is indeed the right way to do it, this is _technically_ creating a custom theme...

Comment: This is working just fine, although it needs some fine tuning in some themes to get all the components to change color. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Alexander's answer is the correct one for lasting changes. If you need ad-hoc style changes, look at the `Ext.util.CSS` class and its method `updateRule`, which allows you to change individual styles for css classes. This requires some fiddling however, because the base color is used in many different places and also in lighter/darker variations.

`swapStyleSheet` lets you change the entire theme or variations of theme overrides.

Comment: This seems like the way to go to customize other colors and components. I'm taking the css class names from "build\development\[appname]\classic\resources\[appname]-all.css" . Am I doing it right??

Comment: You would use your browser's dev-tools inspector and find the css you want to change, e.g. `Ext.util.CSS.updateRule('.x-window-header-default-top', 'background-color', 'yellow')`

Comment: But really that is a special case, usually you always override your theme as Alexander described or create multiple custom themes.